# Excel percentages with no sign

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to color green or red depending if the value is >0 or <0. I have 3 columns that look like this:

[image]

The first column will tell me if the business over/under performed in comparison to what we had budgeted. the second column will give me the % of that variance to total budget. and the third one is my original budget.
in this case, since my budget was <0 and my variance is >0, my % to budget (column 2) is showing as negative.
Is there a way to show these percentages with no sign? I just want to know how much is the variance of the total budget.
current formula I'm using is:`=iferror(A1/C1,0)`

Any idea on how to do this?
Thanks

Comment: Depending on what you want to do, either format the cell to look that way, or use the `ABS(…` function around your formula.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Custom number format: "0%;0%;0%"
The first '0%' tells the cell how to format a positive number
The second '0%' tells it how to format a negative number
The third tells it how to format a zero

This only hides the sign. It's still the same number, just displayed differently.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ABS()`.

In your case you can use `=ABS(iferror(A1/C1,0))`